# Do I need to be concerned about signed vs unsigned with javascript bitwise operations?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have a series of flags such as `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x100`, `0x200`.

Flags are expected to be provided as an unsigned integer and I'm testing for flag existence using code like `if(flags & flag)`.

To append flags I'm using code such as `flags=flags | flag`.

In short (pun not intend‍♂️), do I need to be casting these operations to unsigned since `flags` needs to be unsigned? If so, does that mean appending `>>> 0` to each case above?

P.S. Sorry for the lazy examples, posting from my phone.

Comment: @Dai: I don't see what problem you think could happen with `if (flags & 0x2)` that wouldn't happen with `if ((flags & 0x2) === 0x2)`. It's not like the `&` is going to return `"zero"` or something.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, assuming that `flags` is a number-type. Things get weird when `flags` is actually `[]` or `undefined` or `NaN` and so on.

Comment: @Dai: Even in such cases, `&` is still going to return a 32-bit integer - see the [ECMAScript spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators). All your examples give `0`.

Comment: There are a few cases where `&` will raise a TypeError - for example, if you try to `&` a Symbol - but when it does return something, it returns a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, you're right. I retract my earlier comment :)

Comment: Appreciate the conversation here. Do I need to be casting these to unsigned before and/or after the bitwise operations?